# Submitting a model in a View back to the controller comes back as NULL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core

0

I have a Model that contains a List as one property member. When I do an HTTP GET with a list of strings it works well because I build a list of textboxes that has the values in it from the List, but when I do a "Submit" using an HTTP POST, everything is passed back correctly but the field that is List comes back as NULL. Why is NULL passed back and not a list of strings?

Extract from Model:

```
public class OIRModel
{
    public string SearchCadenceName { get; set; }
    public string SearchVendor { get; set; }
    public List<string> _Vendors { get; set; }
}
```

Extract from View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model._Vendors)
{
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item)</td>
        </tr>
}
```

Extract from Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditPost(OIRModel _model)
```

Comment: what does the HTML for the `<form />` tag look like?

Answer (score -1):

You can build the list of textboxes like below:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model._Vendors.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model._Vendors[i])</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mark C, if this is not the case, you could show us the whole form codes.